# Left arrow key prints `^[[D` when I do `sudo su otheruser` on headless Ubuntu 18, via ssh using MobaXterm on Win 10. How do I move one char left?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, sudo, su, mobaxterm

I sometimes need to login as the application user to do some manual operations, debugging, or handling a failure. I don't want to go into our password management system to fetch the application user's password and set up a new session, I'd just like to go `sudo su otheruser`, and do the operations I need. But when I do, I always have to be really careful about what I type, because I can't use my left arrow to fix typos or make adjustments. It then just prints stuff like `^[[A`, `^[[B`, `^[[C` or `^[[D`. How can I make it actually do the operations instead of printing them out?

Comment: Check & compare your terminal settings, e.g. `$ env | less` both locally and in your ssh session.

Comment: @Hannu I'm guessing it is `SHELL` I'm looking for. My user on the server says `SHELL=/bin/bash`, the application user I'm `su`-ing into says `SHELL=/bin/sh`. Locally I'm running Windows, so I'm not sure what to look for there. Should I try to change to bash in the application user too?

Comment: `$ echo $TERM` -> often saying "xterm" -  the basic setting. This must **match** the terminal emulation you have active locally (on the machine you're running ssh from, e.g. from cmd.com on windows). The displayed characters you see; `^[[A` (esc [ A) are "ANSI" sequences for the keys; printed "RAW" instead of being interpreted by the terminal.

Comment: I'm a Linux user so cannot advice you on what you need other than trying out e.g. PuTTY or KiTTY for better terminal emulation.

Comment: Thanks. Your input helped me solve it. Made me understand it had something to do with the shell program etc. I only had to run `bash` and it got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution was to just run `bash` after I logged in to the application user:

```
sudo su otheruser
bash
# Now arrows work as expected.
```

[Another one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/277645/206121) I found was to do:

```
sudo su -s /bin/bash - otheruser
```

In retrospect this question might not fit well in superuser. I just thought it was an issue with MobaXterm, when it was simple a linux question.

Comment: Please verify the setting of `$TERM`, you might reveal the actual problem.

Comment: `TERM=xterm` on the app user, and `TERM=xterm` for my own server user.

Comment: Well, might then be that the remote "sh" doesn't "understand" this.

Comment: @Hannu: It sounds like the shell _is_ the actual problem. Not all of them actually implement full line editing with arrow keys (via readline) – the minimal "dash" actually does not.

Comment: yes indeed, that is what I tried to express with the above - a simplified form of the same.